# Scale font size based on screen density

Tags: java, android

I know in Android that you can scale the images based on screen densities. 
For instance, if mdpi is the baseline,

- hdpi = 1.5 * mdpi
- xhdpi = 2 * mdpi
- xxhdpi = 3 * mdpi
- xxxhdpi = 4 * mdpi.

Are there similar values for font size?

Comment: Font sizes in Android adjust automatically based on the density of the screen and user font settings if you use 'sp'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need to do is to perform a conversion using the `scaleDensity` ([here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#scaledDensity) the documentation) value, member of the [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)
class. From the documentation

> A scaling factor for fonts displayed on the display. This is the same
>   as density, except that it may be adjusted in smaller increments at
>   runtime based on a user preference for the font size.

Comment: So based on this value, the font size has to be set programmatically right?

Comment: Depends on the use cases. In case of a TextView, setTextSize does the conversion for you.

Comment: One last question, If I set the font size in mdpi, do I need to set the font size for other screen densities (hdpi, xhdpi, etc.)? Does Android scale automatically the font size based on screen densities?

Comment: android takes care of it

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same values might be used for font size

```
android:textSize="18dp"
```

Although it's recommended to use `sp` (scale independent pixels). It's almost the same thing as `dp`, but it might scale-up based on user accessibility settings (for instance, if you haw low vision, you can scale-up font size affecting how `sp` is calculated). So, in the end it becomes:

```
android:textSize="18sp"
```

Once again, if you're using default settings, 1dp == 1sp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programmatically:

```
view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create these 5 folders in your `res` folder
   `values-ldpi`
   `values-mdpi`
   `values-hdpi`
   `values-xhdpi`
   `values-xxhdpi`
2. And add `dimens.xml` in each folder.
3. Paste this code in each dimens.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="font_size">72sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Depending of Screen density change the font size.

Comment: this answer is not correct, i have two different devices that are xxhdpi and one of them blows up the font so much